# spark-cassandra-connector on EMR serverless (PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, amazon-emr, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm working on getting an application running on EMR Serverless and am having trouble pulling in the spark-cassandra-connector. I have no issue pulling it on my local, but all of my attempts at using the library on EMR Serverless have failed.

When I include the library using `--jars s3://XXX/XXXX/spark-cassandra-connector-driver_2.12-3.2.0.jar`, I error out on the following line

```
d = spark \
    .read \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
    .options(table="YYYY", keyspace="YYY") \
    .load()
```

with the error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o121.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at
http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

When I try to add the package using `--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.2.0`, the application times out with

```
com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-5ee06249-c545-4b92-804f-ecedd322158a;1.0
    confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 524554ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
    :: modules in use:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.12;3.2.0

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/hadoop/.m2/repository/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.pom

      -- artifact com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.12;3.2.0!spark-cassandra-connector_2.12.jar:

      file:/home/hadoop/.m2/repository/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /home/hadoop/.ivy2/local/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.12;3.2.0!spark-cassandra-connector_2.12.jar:

      /home/hadoop/.ivy2/local/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/jars/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12.jar

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.pom

      -- artifact com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.12;3.2.0!spark-cassandra-connector_2.12.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      https://repos.spark-packages.org/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.pom

      -- artifact com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.12;3.2.0!spark-cassandra-connector_2.12.jar:

      https://repos.spark-packages.org/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.12;3.2.0: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

    Server access error at url https://repos.spark-packages.org/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

    Server access error at url https://repos.spark-packages.org/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.2.0/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))
```

I'm betting the `--package` issue comes from a firewall configuration problem, but I'm not seeing any way to open up access. As for the `--jars` issue, I'm not sure why pulling in the `.jar` isn't enough for Spark to recognize the `org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra` format.

Any help on either issue would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the issue with `--packages` most probably due your egress settings that prevent accessing the Maven central.

To use `--jars` you need to specify all necessary jars, like, `driver`, `connector`, Java driver, etc.  The easiest way to avoid this is to use so-called assembly build that is [available on Maven Central too](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12/3.2.0) with `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12:3.2.0` coordinate. Just download referenced jar file.

Comment: using the assembly instead of just the driver fixed my issue, thanks so much!

Comment: Note that --packages is only supported from emr-6.7.0 and up and you need to configure your Serverless application with a VPC that has outbound access.

If you need to create a custom uberjar with your deps, check out how to do this with Docker at https://github.com/aws-samples/emr-serverless-samples/tree/main/examples/pyspark/dependencies#packaging-dependencies-into-an-uberjar